# Remove specific select id data from MyBatis cache

Tags: mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

```
<mapper namespace="src.main.domain.EqMapper">
    <cache eviction="FIFO" size="512" readOnly="true"/>

    <select id="getStoreIdAndEqId" resultType="String" flushCache="false" useCache="true">
        select count(author) from blog
    </select>
    <select id="getWholeData" resultType="java.util.LinkedHashMap" flushCache="false" useCache="true">
        select * from blog
    </select>
</mapper>

Configuration configuration = MyBatisUtil.getSqlSessionFactory().getConfiguration(); 
Collection<Cache> caches = configuration.getCaches(); 
for (Cache cache : caches) { 
    Lock w = cache.getReadWriteLock().writeLock(); 
    w.lock(); 
    try { 
        cache.clear(); 
    } finally { 
        w.unlock(); 
    } 
}
```

The above cache logic clears all cache. Is it possible to clear a specific cache? I want to delete `getStoreIdAndEqId` cache and not `getWholeData` cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select id="getStoreIdAndEqId" resultType="String" flushCache="true" useCache="false">
     select count(author) from blog
</select>
<select id="getWholeData" resultType="java.util.LinkedHashMap" flushCache="false" useCache="true">
     select * from blog
</select>
```

Comment: Is it possible to change values of `flushCache="true/false"` dynamically. Is it possible to take control of that.

Comment: Apparently, it is possible. Try [this](http://ronaldxq.blogspot.com/2014/07/remove-single-entry-from-mybatis-cache.html)